# session[:_csrf_token] not same as csrf_meta_tags in rails 4.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have just upgraded to rails 4.2.1
Found session[:_csrf_token] not same as csrf_meta_tags
I suspect because I am in development model, but does not know why.

Does anyone know why this change happen?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of rails 4.2 the token added to forms or in the meta tag is [masked](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#masked-authenticity-tokens): it is encrypted with a 32bit value (which forms part of the submitted value) that changes on a per request basis.

This masking isn't to make the token any more secret - it is to help mitigate attacks such as BREACH

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so what if I want to compare session[:_csrf_token] with csrf_meta_tags?

Comment: I ask this is because: http://www.sitepoint.com/realtime-mini-chat-rails-faye/ There are Security section indicate to compare these.

Comment: @xnjiang sounds like the article is out of date then - it predates rails 4.2

Answer (score 0):

As @frederick-cheung has already said, `form authenticity token` is now [masked](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#masked-authenticity-tokens) and varies with each request in order to mitigate SSL attacks.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/chumakoff/c76fffbe19ab5bf70291f0085ce881f7) is a code example that shows how to unmask `form authenticity token` to compare it with `session[:_csrf_token]`

```
def unmask_authenticity_token(authenticity_token)
  # this must be the same as ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection::AUTHENTICITY_TOKEN_LENGTH
  token_length = 32

  masked_token = Base64.strict_decode64(authenticity_token)

  one_time_pad = masked_token[0...token_length]
  encrypted_csrf_token = masked_token[token_length..-1]

  bytes = encrypted_csrf_token.bytes
  one_time_pad.each_byte.with_index { |b, i| bytes[i] ^= b }

  Base64.strict_encode64(bytes.pack("C*"))
end
```